# addressing and allocating memory for c struct array

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

While writing an adjacency list from scratch I'm facing some problem with addressing and allocating memory for an array of struct. (ignore directed/undirected list).
After hours of debugging I've found the code is keeping (updates) only the last two inputs in the adjacency list. 
***I want to know what and how actually I'm messing up the memory allocation and accessing it.***
 
Don't forget to give me further study links on this topic/issue, please. Thank's in advance.
Here's my code-

```
/*a single node of an adjacency list*/
typedef struct adjList{

    int dest;
    struct adjList *next;

} adjList;


/*Image of a graph...*/

typedef struct Image{

    int source;
    adjList *head;

} Image;


void add_adj_edge(Image graph[], int source, int destiny);

int main() {

    int vertices = 6;
    Image graph[vertices];

     //need not to mention detailed here    
   // initialize_graph(graph, vertices);

    add_adj_edge(graph, 1, 2);
    add_adj_edge(graph, 1, 4);
    add_adj_edge(graph, 1, 5);
    add_adj_edge(graph, 1, 6);
    print_graph(graph, vertices);
    printf("graph[1].head->dest: %d\n", graph[1].head->dest);

    return 0;
}





void add_adj_edge(Image *graph, int src, int dest){

    adjList *cache = malloc(sizeof(adjList));
    /*create a single node*/
    cache->dest = dest;
    cache->next = NULL;

    if(graph[src].head == NULL){
            graph[src].head = cache;

    }


    else{

            while( graph[src].head->next != NULL){
                graph[src].head = graph[src].head->next;
            }

            graph[src].head->next = cache;

    }

    return;

}
```

The output

```
        node: 1    5 6 
        node: 2    
        node: 3    
        node: 4    
        node: 5    
        node: 6    
        graph[1].head->dest: 5

Instead of 

        node: 1   2 4 5 6
        node: 2    
        node: 3    
        node: 4    
        node: 5    
        node: 6 
        graph[1].head->dest: 2
```

Comment: `graph[src].head = graph[src].head->next`. That is wrong. You need to use a temp variable to traverse the list. Not change the head pointer on each iteration.

Comment: First, you have allocated `Image graph[vertices];`, but never you are setting `..head = NULL;`, so the if-condition `if(graph[src].head == NULL)` in `add_adj_edge()` is always `false`.

Comment: @J.Piquard I've allocated each head to `NULL` in `initialize_graph(graph, vertices)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned as comment, your source code has some missing and also misunderstanding on how to update a linked-list.

**First problem:** (allocating `Image graph[vertices];` in your `main()` doesn't initialize value).

> It is necessary to set `adjList *head;` property to NULL to be sure
>   that `if(graph[src].head == NULL)` will be true at the first access.

```
int vertices = 6;
Image graph[vertices];
for(int i=0;i<vertices;i++) {
    graph[i].head = NULL;  // list is empty
    graph[i].source = 0; // or what ever you want
}
```

**Second problem:** (when adding a new node at the end of a linked-list, it is necessary to use a temporary variable to explore previous node).

> If you are using `graph[src].head = graph[src].head->next;` you will
>   overwrite all previous nodes by the last one.

Use the following method in `add_adj_edge()`to explore nodes:

```
        adjList *pTmp;

        // point to the first node
        pTmp = graph[src].head;
        // explore node until the last has no node
        while( pTmp->next != NULL){
            pTmp = pTmp->next;
        }
        // update the next node
        pTmp->next = cache;
```

Comment: I've allocated each head to `NULL` in `initialize_graph(graph, vertices)`

Comment: So, in my answer, the **"First problem"** is solved, but did you test my solution for your **"Second problem"** ?

Comment: Let you know in time bro